# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool error

Tags: arrays, boolean

This is displayed in the row where the error should be

if(!empty($curColor))
$curColor = sprintf(' style="color:%s;"', $curColor);

where do I have to change something?

to find the error maybe someone knows where the error is

Comment: I would suggest you add tags that explain a bit the context---in which language is that, and is that in some web framework or somewhere else?